# vercel 404 page css not loading css when an extra / is found after the domain name

Tags: html, css, vercel

I am using vercel to host my website and I used the vercel.json file to route my 404 page. The 404 page works fine if the domain is something like this: `https://example.com/first`
[image]

But if the domain is like https://example.com/first/second it won't load the CSS or javascript because the file route is now different.

[image]

here is my vercel.json

```json
{
  "routes": [
    { "handle": "filesystem" },
    { "src": "/(.*)", "status": 404, "dest": "/404.html" }
  ]
}
```

How can I solve this problem? I'm not using a serverless function, you can see the source code at https://github.com/crispy-cream/specs. Files are

- https://github.com/Crispy-Cream/specs/blob/main/404.html
- https://github.com/Crispy-Cream/specs/blob/main/_assets/css/404.css
- https://github.com/Crispy-Cream/specs/blob/main/_assets/scripts/404.js